# how to add linehieght plugin to ckeditor

Tags: laravel, ckeditor

I have downloaded lineheight plugin from https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/lineheight, i have also copied lineheight folder to following plugins folder.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\AQPGS\public\vendor\unisharp\laravel-ckeditor\plugins
```

And i have configured the cofig.js file in ckeditor `config.extraPlugins = 'linehieght';`.
And i have also added `{ name: 'styles' ,    groups: ['lineheight']},` .
But when i refresh the page ckeditor disappear from the page.

i need this plugin how can i add it to ckeditor????
[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's called: linehieght and not lineheight? You have a typo

Comment: sorry it's lineheight, but still not working??

Comment: Do you have an error in your console log?

Comment: yes it has following error <br/>     0: [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource name "lineheight" was not found at "http://aqpgs.com/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/plugins/lineheight/plugin.js?t=H7HG".

Comment: ok thanks for comments i did it.

Comment: i solve it using the console log error message. thank you

Comment: Happy programming :)

Comment: Hi @RiazKhan. How did you solve it? I faced the same error using ckeditor4-react.